# setContentView is not working on Android without static references to main activity

Tags: android

I created a Login Activity, it provides the login interface of the app.

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
```

I extended the Activity class for it, and then overriden the onCreate method like this:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        this.username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loginUsername);
        this.password = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.passwordLogin);

        this.username.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);

        ImageView banner = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
        banner.setImageResource(R.drawable.banner);
    }
```

Problem is.. nothing shows up on the simulator.

However this works perfectly fine:

```
MainActivity.getInstance().setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
```

but is a very pad practice to use and will cause frequent crashes. What could be wrong? No console errors show.

LoginActivity class:

```
package flarehubpe.xflare.flarehub;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Bundle;

import flarehubpe.xflare.flarehub.utils.jsonData;

import org.json.JSONException;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    public TextView username;
    public TextView password;

    public boolean authenticated = false;
    public ProfileActivity profileManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        this.username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loginUsername);
        this.password = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.passwordLogin);

        this.username.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);

        ImageView banner = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
        banner.setImageResource(R.drawable.banner);
    }

    public void spawnToDevice(){
    }

    public void login(){
        try {
            jsonData data = RestAPI.getResponse("http://xxx/login.php?username=" + this.username.getText().toString() + "&password=" + this.password.getText().toString());
            if(data == null){
                sendAlert("Error", "Something went wrong... This is embarrassing. Please contact @ on twitter.","Ok");
                return;
            }
            if(!data.getString("error").contains("false")){
                sendAlert("Uh oh", data.getString("error"), "Ok");
                return;
            }
            sendAlert("Success!", "You are now logged in.", "Ok");
            createProfile(this.username.getText().toString(), this.password.getText().toString(), data.getInteger("coins"), data.getInteger("rankid"), data.getInteger("wins"), data.getInteger("kills"), data.getInteger("deaths"));
            this.username.setText("");
            this.password.setText("");
            this.authenticated = true;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void createProfile(String username, String password, Integer coins, Integer randid, Integer wins, Integer kills, Integer deaths){
        this.profileManager = new ProfileActivity(username, password, coins, randid, wins, kills, deaths);
    }

    public void sendAlert(String title, String content, String buttonText) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);
        alertDialog.setMessage(content);
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, buttonText,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    public void logout(){
        this.authenticated = false;
        this.spawnToDevice();
    }
}
```

Comment: "Problem is.. nothing shows up on the simulator." -- are you ever calling `startActivity()` to display `LoginActivity`? "but is a very pad practice to use and will cause frequent crashes" -- having a `static` reference to an activity is a bad practice.

Comment: Since `MainActivity` works are you sure you are in your `LoginActivity` and not the MainActivity?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you use a wrong context for activity_login.xml

you should have the context of your activity :

```
tools:context=".package_name.LoginActivity"
```